# LinearSVC() differs from SVC(kernel='linear')

Tags: scikit-learn, libsvm

When data is offset (not centered in zero), `LinearSVC()` and `SVC(kernel='linear')` are giving awfully different results. (EDIT: the problem might be it does not handle non-normalized data.)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
plot.ioff()
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC


def plot_hyperplane(m, X):
    w = m.coef_[0]
    a = -w[0] / w[1]
    xx = np.linspace(np.min(X[:, 0]), np.max(X[:, 0]))
    yy = a*xx - (m.intercept_[0]) / w[1]
    plot.plot(xx, yy, 'k-')

X, y = make_blobs(n_samples=100, centers=2, n_features=2,
                  center_box=(0, 1))
X[y == 0] = X[y == 0] + 100
X[y == 1] = X[y == 1] + 110

for i, m in enumerate((LinearSVC(), SVC(kernel='linear'))):
    m.fit(X, y)
    plot.subplot(1, 2, i+1)
    plot_hyperplane(m, X)

    plot.plot(X[y == 0, 0], X[y == 0, 1], 'r.')
    plot.plot(X[y == 1, 0], X[y == 1, 1], 'b.')

    xv, yv = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(98, 114, 10), np.linspace(98, 114, 10))
    _X = np.c_[xv.reshape((xv.size, 1)), yv.reshape((yv.size, 1))]
    _y = m.predict(_X)

    plot.plot(_X[_y == 0, 0], _X[_y == 0, 1], 'r.', alpha=0.4)
    plot.plot(_X[_y == 1, 0], _X[_y == 1, 1], 'b.', alpha=0.4)

plot.show()
```

This is the result I get:

[image: bug]

(left=LinearSVC(), right=SVC(kernel='linear'))

`sklearn.__version__` = 0.17. But I also tested in Ubuntu 14.04, which comes with 0.15.

I thought about reporting the bug, but it seems too evident to be a bug. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the documentation, they are using different underlying implementations. `LinearSVC` is using liblinear where `SVC` is using libsvm.

Looking closely at the coefficients and intercept, it seems `LinearSVC` applies regularization to the intercept where `SVC` does not.

By adding intercept_scaling, I was able to obtain the same results to both.

```
LinearSVC(loss='hinge', intercept_scaling=1000)
```

[image: Comparsion after intercept scaling]

Comment: Looking at this close, it seems there is an optimization problem with the scale of the variables. Going to extend my answer later.

Comment: Thank you. So, if I do not want to normalize my datasets and I have no time to go one by one, I should stick with `SVC(kernel='linear')`, right?

Comment: `SVC` seems much less finicky :-). It is generally a good idea with any gradient descent optimizer to use feature scaling and mean centering. Any reason you are avoiding it? It can be easily implemented in scikit-learn with a `Pipeline` and `StandardScaler`. It only becomes annoying if you are trying to interpret the coefficients yourself.

Comment: It is just that we are using data from UCI, and we wanted to compare a method of ours with `SVC` using a linear kernel. But yeah, we are going to standardized the data for now, and maybe consider using `SVC` for a final run. `LinearSVC` is naturally much faster.