# What is the difference between LinearSVC and SVC(kernel="linear")?

Tags: scikit-learn, svm

I found [`sklearn.svm.LinearSVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) and [`sklearn.svm.SVC(kernel='linear')`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html) and they seem very similar to me, but I get very different results on Reuters.

```
sklearn.svm.LinearSVC: 81.05% in   28.87s train /    9.71s test
sklearn.svm.SVC      : 33.55% in 6536.53s train / 2418.62s test
```

Both have a linear kernel. The tolerance of the LinearSVC is higher than the one of SVC:

```
LinearSVC(C=1.0, tol=0.0001, max_iter=1000, penalty='l2', loss='squared_hinge', dual=True, multi_class='ovr', fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1)
SVC      (C=1.0, tol=0.001,    max_iter=-1, shrinking=True, probability=False, cache_size=200, decision_function_shape=None)
```

**How do both functions differ otherwise?** Even if I set `kernel='linear`, `tol=0.0001`, `max_iter=1000 and`decision_function_shape='ovr'`the`SVC`takes much longer than`LinearSVC`. Why?

I use `sklearn 0.18` and both are wrapped in the `OneVsRestClassifier`. I'm not sure if this makes the same as `multi_class='ovr'` / `decision_function_shape='ovr'`.

Comment: Can you upgrade to 0.18.2 and see if the results still differ ?

Comment: I believe the version is not the case. The `sklearn` documentation contains the examples of fitting these classifiers. The results differ due to approaches that the models use.

Comment: There are some discussions about it already, maybe check these:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33843981/under-what-parameters-are-svc-and-linearsvc-in-scikit-learn-equivalent
and
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076586/linearsvc-vs-svckernel-linear-conflicting-arguments

Comment: The documentation states that they use different implementations and even using the method from sklearn or accessing directly the low-level implementation can result in different scores.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Truly, `LinearSVC` and `SVC(kernel='linear')` yield different results, i. e. metrics score and decision boundaries, because they use different approaches. The toy example below proves it:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC, SVC

X, y = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

clf_1 = LinearSVC().fit(X, y)  # possible to state loss='hinge'
clf_2 = SVC(kernel='linear').fit(X, y)

score_1 = clf_1.score(X, y)
score_2 = clf_2.score(X, y)

print('LinearSVC score %s' % score_1)
print('SVC score %s' % score_2)

--------------------------
>>>    0.96666666666666667
>>>    0.98666666666666669
```

---

The key principles of that difference are the following:

- By default scaling, `LinearSVC` minimizes the squared hinge loss while `SVC` minimizes the regular hinge loss. It is possible to manually define a 'hinge' string for `loss` parameter in `LinearSVC`.
- `LinearSVC` uses the One-vs-All (also known as [One-vs-Rest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-rest)) multiclass reduction while `SVC` uses the [One-vs-One](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#One-vs.-one) multiclass reduction. It is also noted [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#multi-class-classification). Also, for multi-class classification problem `SVC` fits `N * (N - 1) / 2` models where `N` is the amount of classes. `LinearSVC`, by contrast, simply fits `N` models. If the classification problem is binary, then only one model is fit in both scenarios. `multi_class` and `decision_function_shape` parameters have nothing in common. The second one is an aggregator that transforms the results of the decision function in a convenient shape of `(n_features, n_samples)`. `multi_class` is an algorithmic approach to establish a solution.
- The underlying estimators for `LinearSVC` are **liblinear**, that do in fact penalize the intercept. `SVC` uses **libsvm** estimators that do not. **liblinear** estimators are optimized for a linear (special) case and thus converge faster on big amounts of data than **libsvm**. That is why `LinearSVC` takes less time to solve the problem.

In fact, `LinearSVC` is not actually linear after the intercept scaling as it was stated in the comments section.

Comment: in the [official documentation of scikit learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#mathematical-formulation), it seems that the math formula doesn't indicate the intercept is penalized. or do I misunderstand?

Answer (score -1):

The main difference between them is linearsvc lets your choose only linear classifier whereas svc let yo choose from a variety of non-linear classifiers. however it is not recommended to use svc for non-linear problems as they are super slow. try importing other libraries for doing non-linear classifications.

now the point that even after defining kernel='linear' we don't get same output is because both linearsvc and svc try different approaches while doing the background mathematics. also linearsvc works on  principle of one-vs-rest, and svc works on one-vs-one.