# LinearSVC and roc_auc_score() for a multi-class problem

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a multi-class problem. I tried to calculate the ROC-AUC score using the function `metrics.roc_auc_score()` from `sklearn`. This function has support for multi-class but it needs the estimated probabilities, for that the classifier needs to have the method `predict_proba()` (which `svm.LinearSVC()` does not have).

Here is an example of what I trying to do:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# Get the data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# Create the model
clf = SVC(kernel='linear', probability=True)

# Split the data in train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Train the model
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the test data
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
predicted_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, predicted_proba, multi_class='ovr')
```

I tried to use `svm.SVC()` with a linear kernel and the parameter `probability` set it to `True`. This allows me to use the method `predict_proba()` from this function. The problem is takes a long time to finish compared to `LinearSVC()` when you have a big dataset (the example is really quit because is a small amount of samples). Is there a way to use `LinearSVC()` and `roc_auc_score()` for a multi-class problem?

Comment: Please [reprex]

Comment: Does this help? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_roc.html

Comment: @Grayrigel the problem is that I can't calculate the estimate probabilities with ```svm.LinearSVC()```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a specially dedicated class [`CalibratedClassifierCV`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.calibration.CalibratedClassifierCV.html) for the cases like this:

```
from sklearn import datasets
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split


# Get the data
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X, y = iris.data, iris.target

# Create the model
clf = CalibratedClassifierCV(LinearSVC(max_iter=10000))

# Split the data in train and test
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5, random_state=0)

# Train the model
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict the test data
predicted = clf.predict(X_test)
predicted_proba = clf.predict_proba(X_test)
roc_auc = roc_auc_score(y_test, predicted_proba, multi_class='ovr')
```

As you're choosing between SVC and LinearSVC you may wish to check out this [When should one use LinearSVC or SVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076586/when-should-one-use-linearsvc-or-svc)

Comment: I prefer to use ```LinearSVC()``` because is faster, but as it say un my question I have to calculate the ROC-AUC score. I have a question of your code, why is ```max_iter``` set it to 10000?

Comment: Try without it as see the warning as a reason

Comment: I see. I compare the results your approach give me **0.93** for ROC-AUC score and using ```SVC()``` give me **0.99**.

Comment: These are different algos.... See the link I provided

Comment: How would you plot a reliability curve for multiclass using the above example?