# SVM problem - name 'model_SVC' is not defined

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science, svm

I have a problem with this code:

```
    from sklearn import svm
    model_SVC = SVC()
    model_SVC.fit(X_scaled_df_train, y_train)
    svm_prediction = model_SVC.predict(X_scaled_df_test)
```

The error message is

> NameError
> Traceback (most recent call
> last) ~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14392/1339209891.py in 
> ----> 1 svm_prediction = model_SVC.predict(X_scaled_df_test)
>
> NameError: name 'model_SVC' is not defined

Any ideas?

Comment: Try `from sklearn.svm import SVC` to import SVC. Or change the next line to `model_SVC = svm.SVC()`. See if that works

Answer (score 2):

use:

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

Answer (score 1):

The line `from sklearn import svm` was incorrect. The correct way is

```
from sklearn.svm import SVC
```

The documentation is [sklearn.svm.SVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html). And when I choose this model, I'm mindful of the dataset size. Extracted:

> The fit time scales at least quadratically with the number of samples and may be impractical beyond tens of thousands of samples. For large datasets consider using [LinearSVC](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.LinearSVC.html) instead.

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
```

For more info you could read [When should one use LinearSVC or SVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35076586/when-should-one-use-linearsvc-or-svc)

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while coding with the help of tutorialspoint.com where i was learning about svm and its usage in python implementing in A.I.
the code was

```py
Svc_classifier = svm_classifier.SVC(kernel='linear', 
C=C, decision_function_shape = 'ovr').fit(X, y)
Z = svc_classifier.predict(X_plot)
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
```

so revised code would be

```py
svc_classifier = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', 
C=C, decision_function_shape = 'ovr').fit(X, y)
Z = svc_classifier.predict(X_plot)
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).